# Автоматический экспорт проекта в eclipse (deploy)

Tags: jboss, java-ee, java, eclipse, развертывание

Ситуация: есть проект на Java, тестовый сервак с JBOSS AS7. Вся разработка происходит в eclipse и сборка проекта выполняется его же средствами. 
Суть проблемы: устал экспортировать WAR'ник в папку сервера. Хочу автоматизировать действие сборки и развертывания приложения на сервере.

P.S. Знаю про существование maven'a, но пока использовать не готов =(

Comment: Погуглите [jboss+deployment+eclipse](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=jboss+deployment+eclipse)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это должно помочь: [WTP Tutorials – Building and Running a Web Application](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/BuildJ2EEWebApp/BuildJ2EEWebApp.html). Для других серверов - процедура аналогичная.